# how to extract useful info from output with regular expresson or beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

This is a snippet of the code that I have been working on for a few days. It tries to get a list of sub-domains for a domain using dnsdumpster.com. However, I prints a lot of data that I don't even need.

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://dnsdumpster.com'
    response = s.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
    response.encoding = 'utf-8' # Optional: requests infers this internally
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    input = soup1.find_all('input')
    csrfmiddlewaretoken_raw = str(input[0])
    csrfmiddlewaretoken = csrfmiddlewaretoken_raw[55:119]
    data = {
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : csrfmiddlewaretoken,
        'targetip' : domain
    }
    send_data = s.post(url, data=data, proxies=proxies, headers=headers)
    print(send_data.status_code)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(send_data.text, 'html.parser')
    td = soup2.find_all('td', {"class": "col-md-4"})
    for i in range(len(td)):
        item = str(td[i])
        subdomain = item[0:100]
        print(subdomain)
```

And this is the output.

```
<td class="col-md-4">ns.example.co.eu.<br/>
<a class="external nounderline" data-target="#myModal" d
<td class="col-md-4">0 ex-am-ple.mail.protection.outlook.com.<br/>
<a class="external nounderlin
<td class="col-md-4">blog.example.co.eu<br/>
<a class="external nounderline" data-target="#myModal"
<td class="col-md-4">dari.kardan.edu.af<br/>
```

I want the sub-domain names without the HTML tags and irrelevant data?
And as you can see, the sub-domain names are not uniform.
Can anyone help me with a regular expression or is there any way I can get the information that I want using BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i try to catch the subdomain then in the last few line i clean the subdomain.

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://dnsdumpster.com'
    response = s.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
    response.encoding = 'utf-8' # Optional: requests infers this internally
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    input = soup1.find_all('input')
    csrfmiddlewaretoken_raw = str(input[0])
    csrfmiddlewaretoken = csrfmiddlewaretoken_raw[55:119]
    data = {
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : csrfmiddlewaretoken,
        'targetip' : domain
    }
    send_data = s.post(url, data=data, proxies=proxies, headers=headers)
    print(send_data.status_code)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(send_data.text, 'html.parser')
    td = soup2.find_all('td', {"class": "col-md-4"})
    mydomain = []
    for i in range(len(td)):
        subdomain = td[i].text.strip()
        mydomain.append(subdomain)
        
# filter_mydomain
filtered_subdomain = []
for sub in mydomain:
    if sub.endswith('.'):
        res = sub[:len(sub)-1]
        filtered_subdomain.append(res)
    else:
        filtered_subdomain.append(sub)

print(filtered_subdomain)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks. Happy to help.